# Ignore real value of imfilter in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using imfilter in matlab to calculate convolution between two matrix A and H. My code is

```
B=imfilter(A,H,'replicate');
```

But the result B appears some complex value (Ex: 1+3i). And I want to remove complex values from matrix B (but dimemsion of B is not changed). So, my question is how to remove complex value of matrix B in matlab or similar way how to ignore them when I calculate B+C where C is input real matrix (I only want to calculate sum of real values in two matrix B and C)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the real value of `B` using `real(B)`.
If you want the magnitude of the entries (rather than just the real part) you can use `abs(B)`.
To get the imaginary part you can use `imag(B)`.

So for a complex matrix `B` you can decompose it using either

```
B = real(B) + j*imag(B);
```

or

```
B = abs(B).*exp( j*angle(B) );
```